# Git push creates error

Tags: git, push

I have a programming project on my computer at work and some time ago I wanted to be able to make a backup and work from home on the project. For that I created a bare git repository on the same work computer and I could push/pull without problems.

For a few weeks now I get an error message when I try to push new changes from my working directory at work into the git-repository. When I try to push a second time it works. This is how it looks:

```
>>> git status
On branch polymult
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/polymult'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   myFile.cpp

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> git commit -am'Test'
[polymult 84ff057] Test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 301 bytes | 301.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack should have generated 84ff057984e1344202cea2f788534849bf2b9787, but I can't find it!
To ../../myProject.git/
 ! [remote rejected] polymult -> polymult (bad pack)
error: failed to push some refs to '../../myProject.git/'
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 301 bytes | 301.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../../myProject.git/
   7c81cb5..84ff057  polymult -> polymult
>>>
```

Has anybody an idea what causes this behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

can you verify the connectivity and validity of the objects by running below command?

git fsck --full

Comment: Did the same as above and after each step the check gives this output:

`>>> git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (424/424), done.`

Comment: try running "git gc" command that will probably help cleaning up some unnecessary files and it will optimize your local repository.